# How to deliberately block 404 error in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a private website for personal use only.  I have no interest in anyone else accessing my webserver and want nginx to return absolutely nothing on all invalid uri.

How do I purposefully prevent 404 error (or any other errors) from being emitted for invalid uri?

Comment: What do you mean by ' to return absolutely nothing on all invalid url'. What is 'nothing' on nginx level?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`try_files`](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#trying-several-options) with a 'custom' fallback.

Send a [200 status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) on fallback if the requested file does not exists;

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =200;
}
```

> **try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;**
>
> The last parameter can also be a status code (directly preceded by the equals sign) or the name of a location. In the following example, a 404 error is returned if none of the parameters to the try_files directive resolve to an existing file or directory.